# How to solve linear ODE with time-varying coefficients using Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, matlab

**The Problem**

I currently have the following system of ODEs which I have managed to solve successfully using the `ode23tb` solver in `MATLAB`.

$$(\mathbf{J_c}+\mathbf{J_v}(t))\mathbf{\ddot{\Theta}} + \mathbf{C\dot{\Theta}}+\mathbf{K\Theta} = \mathbf{F}(t) \tag{1}$$

However, using `ode23tb` (or similar solvers) takes time, and the solution has to go through a transient stage before it settles into a repeatable periodic pattern. Hence I have attempted to use Fourier series which might bypass the above problems.

---

**My Attempt**

1. I attempt to solve the problem iteratively where for the first iteration with superscript $^{(1)}$ I take the Fourier transform of the RHS of Eq.(1), i.e. $\mathbf{F}^{(1)}$:

$$\mathbf{F}(t) = \mathbf{F}^{(1)} = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} \mathbf{f}^{(1)}_n e^{in\omega t}$$

2. I remove the time dependence of the $\mathbf{J}_v$ term by taking its average $\mathbf{\bar{J}}_v$, and perform the Fourier transform on Eq.(1) to get a linear set of equations:

$$(-n^2 \omega^2 (\mathbf{J}_c+\mathbf{\bar{J}}_v) + i n \omega \mathbf{C} + \mathbf{K})^{-1} \mathbf{f}^{(1)}_n = \mathbf{c}^{(1)}_n \tag{2}$$

3. Having solved Eq.(2), I can now use the fact that $ \ddot{\mathbf{\Theta}}^{(1)} = \sum -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{c}^{(1)}_n e^{in\omega t}$ to re-calculate the excitation force on the RHS of Eq.(1). So for my second iteration Eq.(1) becomes:
   $$\mathbf{J_c}\mathbf{\ddot{\Theta}} + \mathbf{C\dot{\Theta}}+\mathbf{K\Theta} = \mathbf{F}(t)-\mathbf{J_v}(t)\mathbf{\ddot{\Theta}}^{(1)} \tag{2}$$ Therefore I repeat steps 1 and 2 by setting as $\mathbf{F}^{(2)}$ the entire RHS of Eq.(2) above.

My hope is that after a couple iterations, the values of subsequent solutions of Eq.(2) will converge however the solution amplitudes become higher and higher.

I have also compared the acceleration with the one obtained from `ode23tb` for the first iteration, and they are nearly identical, which shows that at least the first iteration is performed correctly. I sense its my method that is at fault here.

Comment: If you consider $J_v$ as a constant, then you have an LTI system, and its frequency response can be computed analytically?

Comment: That's exactly what I do in step 2 by taking the average of $J_v$. However this provides an inaccurate solution, so when I try to improve this by iterating I can't get the algorithm to converge.